# ON CONFLICT statement not executing

Tags: postgresql, sqlx

When conflict value goes to this query, update is not executed (concerning to `updated_at field`). But insert works perfect with such subquery as `SELECT with joins`

```
INSERT INTO history (tx_hash, user_address, address_from, address_to, value, type, status, submitted_at,
                     coin_id, network_id)
SELECT :tx_hash, :user_address, :address_from, :address_to, :value, :type, :status, :submitted_at,
       c.id, n.id
FROM  (VALUES (:coin_symbol, :network_symbol) ) x
          INNER JOIN coins c on c.symbol = :coin_symbol
          INNER JOIN networks n on n.symbol = :network_symbol
ON CONFLICT (tx_hash)
    DO UPDATE SET (confirmations, status, updated_at) =
                      (excluded.confirmations, excluded.status, now());
```

Table structure [gist](https://gist.github.com/aemet93/982e28b770e09fb7a546965cc6cab842)

Comment: Maybe conflict is not only on `tx_hash` field. You must include all fields which violate unique index  and it looks like your unique index contains multiple fields.

Comment: @Kadet thanks for the answer. But no, PK in this table is single one ```PRIMARY KEY (tx_hash)```

Comment: So PK is single, no other unique indexes, and it contains only one field ? So try to point (for testing purposes) on exact constraint which is violated `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name`. And of course it will be helpful if you attach full table definition

Comment: Table definiton: https://gist.github.com/aemet93/982e28b770e09fb7a546965cc6cab842.

Btw, I've tried your `ON CONSTRAINT` suggestion. Unfortunately - same result.
Interesting thing that request doesn't give me any errors. Because without `on conflict` I should receive an error.

Comment: The fealing, like instead of update its made `do nothing`.

Comment: Really strange, because it works as expected on example data. Without `ON CONFLICT` clause it throws `duplicate key value violates unique constraint` ?

Comment: No, no errors.. I've also tried make this request by hands with duplicated PK simulating `confirmations and status`, and this also does not modify updating fields in the table.

Comment: If no errors, then select inside insert return no rows, so insert statement have no rows to insert

Comment: Exactly! Just figured it out now. I can accept your answer. if you want to post it, because your thoughts pushed me to find the answer. Thanks.